# mongodb finding documents based on field calculation

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection declaring some background tasks. For each task The user can specify a `maxExecution` (in seconds). I also have a field called `startedAt` (a date object) and I need to find all documents where the execution should be stopped (`maxExecution` was reached). Something like `currDate_seconds - maxExecution > startedAt_seconds`.

Any idea on how I should tackle this thing with mongo?

Comment: Are you using the mongo shell or a language driver?

Comment: I'm using pymongo (python)

Comment: Use the `$redact` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoShell something like the following will do the trick:

```
var currentTimeSeconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
db.myCollection.find({
   $where: '(' + currentTimeSeconds + ' - this.maxExecution) > this.startedAt_seconds)'
});
```

The `$where` query operator allows you to query documents using javascript (`this` refers to the document). You can pull the same stunt with any language drivers - construct the `$where` query operator using the current time and you are good to go.

BTW, I do not suggest retrieving the time within the `$where` operator, since it will be changing as the query executes.